# why is MySQL update query is slow?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

```
Update tbldupaudit_workingitems as w inner join
tbldupaudit_auditstatus_temp t on 
Resolved_Status = 0 and
concat(w.Claim_ID, w.DIN) = concat(t.Claim_ID, t.DIN)
SET 
w.Status = t.Status,
w.Audit_Remarks=t.Audit_Remarks,
w.Resolved_By=t.Resolved_By,
w.Resolved_Date=t.Resolved_Date,
w.Resolved_Status = 1;
```

tbldupaudit_workingitems: Rows - 0.4 million approximately and it gets increased on daily basis.
tbldupaudit_auditstatus_temp: Rows - 25 thousand approximately and it may gets increased or decreased.

Process: loading csv file into tbldupaudit_auditstatus_temp table and update tbldupaudit_workingitems if any records that are matched based on Claim_ID &DIN.

This is taking quite a long time to execute but if query runs more than 1:45 hrs then the connection is getting lost.

Show Create Tables:
[image]

is there any thing that we can improve this query performance please advice.
Please do let me know if any more details required to help me but please do not make my question with negative marks as I am new to Stakeoverflow/matter of fact I am new to MySQL(DB coding).

Comment: Are you updating `A` or updating `X`?

Comment: Please read this and pay special attention to the section on query performance. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 Then please [edit] your question to give us more information so we can better help you.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  It might be as simple as a missing composite index.  Also, about how many rows in each table?

Comment: You might be using phpmyadmin or some other UI for mysql. Kindly share the image of your tables structure. This will help resolve your problem.

Comment: in your query you are trying to update table  `A` but setting the value of `X`. First try changing that part.

Comment: Update tbldupaudit_workingitems as w inner join
tbldupaudit_auditstatus_temp t on 
w.Resolved_Status = 0 and
concat(w.Claim_ID, w.DIN) = concat(t.Claim_ID, t.DIN)
SET 
w.Status = t.Status,
w.Audit_Remarks=t.Audit_Remarks,
w.Resolved_By=t.Resolved_By,
w.Resolved_Date=t.Resolved_Date,
w.Resolved_Status = 1; 

I have edited code now. it is taking very less time in my local system but when i move to server it is taking 20 minutes for 500 records.

Comment: Please help me I am bad in explaining problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Image is not usable; let's see the text.

Comment: Is there a `PRIMARY KEY` or any other indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AND concat(w.Claim_ID, w.DIN) = concat(t.Claim_ID, t.DIN)
```

That cannot be optimized.

Probably this would work very well:

```
AND w.Claim_ID = t.Claim_ID
AND w.DIN = t.DIN
```

But it would need a composite index on at least one of the tables:

```
INDEX(Clarim_ID, DIN)
```